# Add payment in django project to extend an expiration date of posts./

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, payment

I have a project where the user can post an Ad and this Ad will be available only for 30 days.

I need to add a payment method to extend the Expiration date of the Ad.

Here is my Ad creation view .

```
class AdvertiseCreateView(APIView):
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
def post(self, request):
    serializer = AdvertiseSerializer(data=request.data)
    user = request.user
    if serializer.is_valid():
        print(user)
        serializer.save(owner = user)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

List view:

```
class AdvertisesListView(APIView):
def get(self, request):
    advertises = Advertise.objects.filter(Q (expiration_date__gt = Now()))
    serializer = AdvertiseSerializer(advertises, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Models:

```
class Advertise(models.Model):
owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="advertise")
category = models.CharField(max_length= 200, choices = CATEGORY)
location = models.CharField(max_length= 200, choices = LOCATIONS)
description = models.TextField(max_length=600)
price = models.FloatField(max_length=100)
expiration_date  = models.DateField(default = Expire_date, blank=True, null=True) #Expire date come from another file
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)


class Meta:
    ordering = ['created_at']


def __str__(self):
    return self.category
```

So the thing is when the user make his payment the  expire date extends.

I need help in payment part.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: That would depend on who your payment vendor was.

Comment: I want it with PayPal or stripe payment.